# Cron not executing jobs

Tags: linux, cron, crontab

I'm having trouble making `cron` work.

I edit my `cron` jobs doing

1. `sudo crontab -u myuser -e`
2. `sudo crontab -u myuser -l` prompts my `cron` tables:

   ```
   #####
   */1 * * * * /home/myuser/Projects/scripts/cron.sh
   ```
3. `/usr/lib/cron/cron.allow` and `.deny` do not exist
4. `ps -A | grep cron && ps aux | grep 'cron' -n`

   ```
   820 ?        00:00:00 cron
   63:root       820  0.0  0.0   2268   884 ?        Ss   17:09   0:00 cron
   ```

Yet the script is not executed.
Am I missing something?

After the `crontab -e` it shows that it is saving to a temporary file. Is this a problem?

Comment: Is your script executable by "myuser"?

Comment: It is (chmod 755)

Comment: After all it is running. Changed the output directory of my test script and it is working. However, how can i run it with root priviligies? Should i just edit the root crontab by doing sudo crontab -e ?

Comment: There are a few ways to get your script running with root privs.  Using the root crontab is the easiest and most straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

Cron check the crontabs every minute to look for changes, create your cron entry and be more patient. crontab's are saved in temporary file until they're read.

Why you're using `sudo` to modify crontab for another user? User without shell? Seems strange to execute an script in that environment.

My answer is basead in vixie's cron, always put version and branch of the software in that type of question.